# How do I find out the total size (MBs) of my Outlook 2003 inbox?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003

Our work just added an inbox quota size and I'm curious how close I am to reaching it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the very top entry in the folder list named '**Mailbox - Your Name**'.  Choose '**Properties for Mailbox...**', then click on the '**Folder Size**' button.

The value for **Total Size (including subfolders)** is what you want.  This is usually displayed in KB.  Divide that value by 1024 to get the size in MB.